# yoaurt cannot build ros-indigo-desktop-full?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello , i have a problem on my antergos based on archlinux that yoaurt can't build ros indigo desktop,

i use this command to install:

```
yaourt --noconfirm --needed ros-indigo-desktop
```

result is:

> ## In file included from
> plugin_context.sip:7:0:
> /tmp/yaourt-tmp-mohamedslama/aur-ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp/src/qt_gui_core-release-release-indigo-qt_gui_cpp-0.2.30-0/src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/../../include/qt_gui_cpp/plugin_context.h:43:19:
> fatal error: QWidget: No such file or
> directory  #include 
> ^ compilation terminated. make[3]: *** [Makefile:18:
> siplibqt_gui_cpp_sipcmodule.o] Error 1
> make[2]: ***
> [src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/build.make:61:
> devel/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qt_gui_cpp/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.so]
> Error 2 make[1]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:375:
> src/qt_gui_cpp_sip/CMakeFiles/libqt_gui_cpp_sip.dir/all]
> Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:128: all]
> Error 2
> ==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
> Aborting...
> ==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp.
> ==> Restart building ros-indigo-qt-gui-cpp ? [y/N]
> ==> ----------------------------------------------
>
> ## ==> Restart building ros-indigo-rqt-gui-cpp ? [y/N]
> ==> -----------------------------------------------
>
> ## ==> Restart building ros-indigo-rqt-image-view ? [y/N]
> ==> --------------------------------------------------
>
> ## ==> Restart building ros-indigo-rqt-common-plugins ? [y/N]
> ==> ------------------------------------------------------
>
> ==> Restart building ros-indigo-desktop ? [y/N]
> ==> -------------------------------------------

after that exit without cann't press any key.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254751/yoaurt-cannot-build-ros-indigo-desktop-full-!!/) by [Mohamed Slama](https://answers.ros.org/users/29368/mohamed-slama/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're missing dependencies. Specifically QWidget. You'll need to make sure you have all the prerequisites before your compile will work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0